# Read csv Oldb c#

Tags: c#, csv, oledb

I have problem with open csv file i have error "not found ISAM". I tried change lines to connection but i didn't found an error. How i could fix it?

```
    private void button7_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        openFileDialog1.Filter = "CSV|*.csv";
        openFileDialog1.ValidateNames = true;
        openFileDialog1.Multiselect = true;
        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            textBox2.Text = openFileDialog1.FileName;
    }

    private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            // string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + textBox2.Text + ";Extended Properties=\"Text;HDR=Yes;FORMAT=Delimited\"";
            string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=" + textBox2.Text + ";Extended Properties=text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited";
            string file = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(textBox2.Text);
            OleDbConnection cons = new OleDbConnection(stringconn);
            OleDbDataAdapter dat = new OleDbDataAdapter("Select * from" + file, cons);
            dat.Fill(dt);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string stringconn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;DataSource=" + textBox2.Text + ";Extended Properties='text;'";
```

Try adding single quotes to the value of Extended Propetries

Comment: ok it works but how i can share it for three columns not all in one?

Comment: you mean for HDR and FMT? `Extended Properties='text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited;'`